# save pointcloud data for multiple frames for object detection

Tags: ros, object-detection, ros-indigo, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use lidar range measurement to generate pointcloud. Now, I want the robot to do a few tasks based on the obstacles' positions in real time. But it takes quite a few frames of lidar to develop a reasonable pointcloud that is enough to recognize an object roughly. How, can I save the lidar data over multiple frames, so that I can access historical data in every successive laser call back?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283044/save-pointcloud-data-for-multiple-frames-for-object-detection/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems like somethint where the `message_filters` package can help. For a simple cache, you could look at the [Cache](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Cache) filter.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2018-02-27**:
Is there any way to cache multiple topics in one callback?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-28**:
I'm not sure. I'd check the `message_filters` C++ api docs. They're quite ok.